# Use .insertAfter with the response from an ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, insertafter

I have a basic dom

```
<div class="outer">
     <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

And an ajax call

```
$.ajax({
     ...
     ...
     success: function(html) {
         //insert 'html' after '.inner'
     }
```

I can't use append here because there will be items after'inner' so I need to insert 'html' specifically after 'inner' but I'm not sure how to use the 'html' with 'inserAfter' here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
$(".inner").after(html);
```

Just be aware, in case you have the class at multiple locations, it will add the html at each location.